# Facebook Exchange Token Expires after 1 day

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app sends a GET to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=APP_ID&
client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

And FB always returns the same token again. The initial expires value is ~1 day and gets decremented. Even after a fresh login which shoulöd get a short lived token and that exchange call which should exchange a short lived with a long lived token always that same short lived token is returned.

So how should one exchange a short lived token with a long live token?

Comment: maybe you should read about [offline access removal](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Comment: I've read it a few times already. And I do it the way it's described there. I get an access token from FB which is a short lived one, then I call the above API to exchange the short lived one with a long lived token, but the successful response from FB sends me just the same short lived token with a short expiration date back. :(